Prove or disprove that the sequence $x_n$ satisfying $|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not cauchy.
I'm given a sequence of real nos. satisfying the condition
$$|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\,\,\forall n \in \mathbb N$$
I'm trying to prove that a sequence satisfying this condition will never be a Cauchy sequence.
My attempt:
I tried constructing $|x_{n+p} - x_n|$,
$$|x_{n+p}-x_n|= |x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}+x_{n+p-1}-x_{n+p-2}+x_{n+p-2}-\cdots+x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
$$\therefore |x_{n+p}-x_n|\le |x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}|+|x_{n+p-1}-x_{n+p-2}|+|x_{n+p-2}- x_{n+p-3}|+\cdots+|x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
$$ |x_{n+p}-x_n|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p-2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Next, I tried creating a lower bound for the sum when $p = n+1$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}+\cdots n+1\,terms\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+(n+1)-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+(n+1)-2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lt\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+(n+1)-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+(n+1)-2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
I can't proceed beyond this point as I can't extend this lower bound to $|x_{2n+1} - x_n|$.
I'm also unable to come up with an example sequence that would satisfy this condition and is Cauchy.

Why don't you just trying to show that the difference between two terms can be made to be less than ϵ
?

You will be doomed to failure. There exists a sequence satisfying those conditions that is a Cauchy sequence.

try $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 1 - 1/\sqrt 2$, $x_3 = 1 - 1/\sqrt 2 + 1/\sqrt 3$ etc.

The difference between consecutive terms being less than $\epsilon$ doesn't imply that the sequence is necessarily Cauchy.

What happens for a sequence of the particular kind satisfying $x^{k+1}-x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (without the modulus)? What can you say about $x^{n+p}-x^n$?

Consider the sequence $x_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$, and $x_{1} = 0$. Show that it satisfies the condition and is Cauchy.

Not only are there Cauchy sequences like this; but there are sequences of this form  converging to any real number.

Where did you get this problem from? As other comments suggest, what you are trying to prove contradicts a general fact: if $a_n$ is any sequence of positive reals such that $a_n \to 0$, then for any real number $x$ you can construct a sequence of reals $x_n$, such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| = a_n$ and such that $x_n \to x$. This follows from standard results on sums of alternating sequences and rearrangements of conditionally convergent sums.

@RobArthan This was more like a doubt, I had a similar question in my assignment where we were asked that a sequence satisfying this condition would it be necessarily Cauchy, so I found a sequence satisfying this condition that wasn't Cauchy $$ x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt k},,\forall n\ge 2,,,& x_1 = 0$$
This sequence is a partial sum of a diverging series. Later on, I was trying to figure out if any sequence satisfying this condition would be Cauchy.

@RobArthan I was unaware of that result, I haven't read about it. Is it covered in any book that you're aware of?

@Ark: I forgot a hypothesis: you also need that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges (which holds in your case where $a_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$. I had a slightly different result in mind from the standard textbook result on rearranging conditionally but not absoulutely convergent series. I will have a think about a reference for it.

I couldn't think of a reference, so I've posted an answer. I hope that helps.

Let me try to write up the general result alluded to in the comments. My proof is a bit clunky, so if anyone can provide a reference or improve my proof, then that would be appreciated. The general result is this:
Lemma: If $a_k$ is any monotonic decreasing sequence of real numbers such that $a_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ and such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges, then for any real number $x$, there is a sequence of signs $s_k \in \{1, -1\}$, such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_k a_k = x$.
For such a sequence of signs, the partial sums $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^ns_ka_k$ satisfy $|S_{n} - S_{n-1}| = |s_na_n| = a_n$. Taking $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ for $n > 1$ and applying the lemma for any $x$ gives us a convergent and hence Cauchy sequence $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n s_ka_k$ with $|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
To prove the lemma, note that the hypotheses imply that the $a_k$ are all positive. We now define the $s_n$ and a sequence of natural numbers $n_m$ by an iterative process. In outline, the process takes the $s_n$ to be $1$ until the partial sum goes above our target $x$ and then takes $s_n$ to be $-1$ until the partial sum goes below $x$ and so on. More formally the stages of the process are as follows for $m = 1, 2, \ldots$:

Let $n_1$ be the least $n$ such that $\sum_{k-1}^{n_1} a_k > x$. Define $s_n = 1$ for $1 \le n \le n_1$. (it may be that $n_1 = 0$; this doesn't matter.) Note that $\sum_{k-1}^{n_1} s_ka_k - x < a_{n_1}$ otherwise $\sum_{k=1}^{n_1 - 1} a_k > x$ contradicting our definition of $n_1$.
Let $n_2$ be the least $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n_1} s_ka_k - \sum_{k=n+1}^{n_2}a_k < x$. Define $s_n = -1$ for $n_1 < n \le n_2$.
Much as in stage 1, we have that $x - \sum_{k-1}^{n_2} s_ka_k < a_{n_2}$ otherwise our definition of $n_2$ would be contradicted.
Let $n_3$ be the least $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n_2} s_ka_k + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n_3}a_k > x$. Define $s_n = 1$ for $n_2 < n \le n_3$.
Again we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{n_3} s_ka_k - x < a_{n_3}$ given our definition of $n_3$.
... and so on with $s_n = 1$ for $n_{2i} < n \le n_{2i+1}$ and $s_n = -1$ for $n_{2i+1}< n \le n_{2i+2}$.

At stage $m$, $n_m$ must exist because $\sum_{k=n_{m-1}}^\infty a_n$ diverges. Also, if we put $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n s_na_n$, we have that $|S_n - x| < a_{n_m}$ for $n_{m-1} \le n < n_m$, because this is true for $n = n_{m-1}$ as noted above and continues to hold while $n < n_m$ by construction. It follows that $S_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, since $a_n \to 0$. I.e., that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_ka_k = x$, which completes the proof of the lemma.
